# Run object's function in resize event js

Tags: javascript

I have created a class using JavaScript

```
function fan(top, left) {
    this.top = top;
    this.left = left;
    this.setPos = function setPos(x, y){
        //some code
    }
}

var fan2 = new fan(10, 10);
fan2.setPos(20, 20); //this function can run

window.onresize = function resize(){
    fan2.setPos(30, 30); //can't run
}
```

How can I run it?
When I show browser's console, It shows nothing.
Thanks for helping me

Comment: Your code seems right to me, what do you mean by _can't run_ inside the `onresize` event ?

Answer (score 1):

It works: https://jsfiddle.net/2bvu5L4t/

But you don't need a function name:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    fan2.setPos(30, 30); // can run
}
```

another way would be:

```
function resize() {
    fan2.setPos(30, 30);
}
window.onresize = resize;
```

Comment: I think it actually works to do `window.resize = function resize () { ... }`

Comment: @NathanP. yes, I added the example

Comment: both of them can run. This is my fault @NathanP. I will delete the tag :)